# Is it possible to create a site using just jquery, javascript and mysql?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I was wondering if it's possible to do it, using Javascript on the server, but without using PHP or ASP. Is this a common practice?

I would like to access mysql db, but I prefer not to use PHP or ASP. So using only Javascript  server code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check out node.js.

Comment: JavaScript doesnt need a server to run. To answer your question though, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using Javascript on the server

If you mean *client-side Javascript running in the browser* doing operations that change stuff directly on the server, then the answer is no. You need a layer running on server side that authenticates accesses, stores data, etc. If this were possible using client-side JavaScript, everybody and their dog could alter your web site. How would you like that?

There are [server-side JavaScript implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Server-side_JavaScript) but I don't think this is what you are asking for. They require a specific server-side setup.

Comment: Yes, I mean server side Javascript. I need to access mysql db.

Comment: @codergal do you have a JavaScript server product like node.js installed? If yes, then I don't really understand your question, because you already know it is possible. If no, can you set one up? Note that this is a lot of work and a completely new way of doing things. It's probably more complex to get into than PHP or ASP, and has a different programming paradigm that you need to get your head around. Are you prepared for that?

Comment: I don't have node.js. I already use ASP, but I was just wondering if it's possible to  make a site using only JS/Jquery. And my conclusion now - yes, it's possible, but a lot easier with the ASP tools. Thanks.

Comment: @codergal I see. Yeah, that conclusion sounds good - delving in to server side JavaScript *just* for the convenience of having one language in the front end and the back end is probably not worth it, as it's a huge paradigm change in how you do things on server side.